# Looking for Fuel Injectors for a Renault Clio Expression 1.5 cdi 2006 plate

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, fuel-injection, renault, fuel-injectors

I am looking at buying a set of fuel injectors for my car but not sure of what part number I can use.

Equally can you buy a manual for car parts?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.